# Natural exponential function with noncommutative exponents.

Tags: exponential-function, quantum-mechanics

I've been studying Quantum Mechanics, and I'm stuck in this problem:

Show that if $[A, B] = k$ then $e^{A} e^{B} = e^{A + B  +\frac{1}{2} [A, B]}$, where k is a constant and A and B are operators.

There's a tip to write $e^{\lambda A} e^{\lambda B}$, differentiate, then integrate and set $\lambda = 1$, but I can't get to the result.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $C(\lambda) = e^{\lambda A}e^{\lambda B}$. 
Then 
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{d\lambda} C
&= A C + C B \\
&= A C + B C + [C,B].
\end{align*}
But, since $[XY,Z]=X[Y,Z]+[X,Z]Y$, 
\begin{align*}
[C,B] &= [e^{\lambda A}e^{\lambda B},B] \\
&= e^{\lambda A}[e^{\lambda B},B] 
 + [e^{\lambda A},B]e^{\lambda B}  \\
&= [e^{\lambda A},B]e^{\lambda B}.
\end{align*}
Prove by induction that $[A^n,B]=n A^{n-1}[A,B]$. 
(This is a standard calculation.) 
Then 
\begin{align*}
[e^{\lambda A},B] 
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^n}{n!}[A^n,B] \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^n}{n!}n A^{n-1}[A,B] \\
&= \lambda \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^m}{m!}A^m [A,B] \\
&= \lambda e^{\lambda A}[A,B].
\end{align*}
Thus, 
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{d\lambda} C
&= (A+B)C + \lambda e^{\lambda A}[A,B]e^{\lambda B} \\
&= (A+B+\lambda [A,B])C,
\end{align*}
if $[A,B]=k$. 
Therefore, up to a multiplicative constant that may be determined to be the identity, 
$$C(\lambda)=e^{\lambda(A+B)+\frac{\lambda^2}{2}[A,B]}.$$
Since $C(1)=e^A e^B$, 
$$e^A e^B = e^{A+B+\frac{1}{2}[A,B]},$$
as claimed.

Answer (score 1):

You may e.g. show first that $A^n B = B A^n + k n A^{n-1}$ so  that $e^{\lambda A} B = B e^{\lambda A} + k \lambda  e^{\lambda A}$
Then $f(\lambda)=e^{\lambda A} e^{\lambda B}$ has as derivative
$$ f'(\lambda) = A f(\lambda) + f(\lambda) B = 
       (A + B + k \lambda ) f(\lambda)$$
from which $$f(\lambda)= \exp (\lambda A+\lambda B+k \lambda^2/2 )$$
and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\mrm{f}\pars{\lambda} \equiv
> \expo{-\lambda A}\expo{\lambda\pars{A + B}}\,,\qquad
> \bracks{A,B} = k = \mbox{constant}}$.

\begin{align}
\totald{\mrm{f}\pars{\lambda}}{\lambda} & =
-\expo{-\lambda A}A\expo{\lambda\pars{A + B}} +
\expo{-\lambda A}\pars{A + B}\expo{\lambda\pars{A + B}} =
\expo{-\lambda A}B\expo{\lambda A}\expo{-\lambda A}\expo{\lambda\pars{A + B}}
\\[5mm] & =
B\pars{\lambda}\mrm{f}\pars{\lambda}\label{1}\tag{1}
\\&
\end{align}
where $\ds{B\pars{\lambda} \equiv \expo{-\lambda A}B\expo{\lambda A}}$.

---

Moreover,
\begin{align}
\totald{B\pars{\lambda}}{\lambda} & =
-\expo{-\lambda A}AB\expo{\lambda A} +\expo{-\lambda A}BA\expo{\lambda A} =
-\expo{-\lambda A}\bracks{A,B}\expo{\lambda A} =
-\expo{-\lambda A}k\expo{\lambda A} = -k
\\[5mm]
\implies & \quad B\pars{\lambda} = B - k\lambda
\end{align}

---

Eqtn. \eqref{1} becomes:
$$
\totald{\mrm{f}\pars{\lambda}}{\lambda} -
\pars{B - \lambda k}\mrm{f}\pars{\lambda} = 0\quad\implies\quad
\totald{}{\lambda}\bracks{\exp\pars{-B\lambda + \half\,k\lambda^{2}}\mrm{f}\pars{\lambda}} = 0
$$
Then,
\begin{align}
\exp\pars{-B\lambda + \half\,k\lambda^{2}}\mrm{f}\pars{\lambda} & =
\mrm{f}\pars{0} = \mathbf{1}\,,\qquad\forall\ \lambda
\\[5mm]
\implies\quad\mathbf{1} =
\expo{-B + k/2}\,\,\,
\overbrace{\expo{-A}\expo{A + B}}^{\ds{=\ \mrm{f}\pars{1}}}\ &\ =\
\expo{-B}\expo{-A}\,\,\expo{A + B + k/2}
\end{align}

---

$$
\color{#f00}{\expo{A}\expo{B}} = \expo{A + B + k/2} =
\color{#f00}{\expo{A + B + \bracks{A,B}/2}}\,\,\,\,,\qquad
\bracks{A,B} = \mbox{constant}
$$